# A simple car leasing company

Tags: python, beginner

I am a beginner at coding with Python. I am excited because I wrote a program that works in JupyterLab, but I know I can make it shorter. For example, I feel I should not need to write so many boolean operators, and print statements. Also, I am not sure if the break I put at the end is ideal. Can you advise me?

Purpose: This program computes and displays information for a company that leases vehicles to its customers. The program will compute and display the amount of money charged for that customer's vehicle rental for a specified customer. The program will run until Q or q is chosen to quit. The customer has two classification codes b or d and if any other code is entered, an error should appear but the program continues to run. Also, if the ending odometer reading is less than or equal to the starting odometer reading then an error should appear but the program continues to run.

```
Name = str(input("Enter the customer's first and last name: "))

while True:
    ClassCode = str(input("Enter the customer's classification code (b or d) or enter q to quit: "))
    DaysRented = int(input("Enter the number of days the vehicle was rented: "))
    Start_Odometer = int(input("Enter the vehicle's six-figure odometer reading at the start of the rental period: "))
    End_Odometer = int(input("Enter the vehicle's six-figure odometer reading at the end of the rental period: "))
    if End_Odometer <= Start_Odometer:
        print()
        print("\033[1m" + "Please enter an ending odometer reading greater than the starting odometer reading")
    if ClassCode.upper() == "B" :
        DaysCost = (DaysRented * 40)
        DistanceCost = ((End_Odometer - Start_Odometer) * 0.25)        
        Bill = DaysCost + DistanceCost
        FullClassCode = "Budget"
        print()
        print('\033[4m{}\033[0m'.format('Welcome to JDB Car Rental Service'))
        print("Customer Bill (",(Name),")")
        print()
        print("\t\tClassification code is ",ClassCode,"(",FullClassCode,"):")
        print("\t\tRented the vehicle for ", DaysRented,"days")
        print("\t\tThe vehicle's odometer reading at the start of the rental period is: ",Start_Odometer)
        print("\t\tThe vehicle's odometer reading at the end of the rental period is: ",End_Odometer)
        print("\t\tThe number of miles driven during the rental period is: ",End_Odometer - Start_Odometer)
        print("\t\tTotal summary for the rental period is: ", "($",DaysCost, " for ",DaysRented," days and $", DistanceCost, " for ", End_Odometer - Start_Odometer, " miles = $",Bill,")")
    elif ClassCode.upper() == "D" and End_Odometer - Start_Odometer <= 150 :
        DaysCost = (DaysRented * 60)
        DistanceCost = 0        
        Bill = DaysCost + DistanceCost
        FullClassCode = "Daily"
        print()
        print('\033[4m{}\033[0m'.format('Welcome to JDB Car Rental Service'))
        print("Customer Bill (",(Name),")")
        print()
        print("\t\tClassification code is ",ClassCode,"(",FullClassCode,"):")
        print("\t\tRented the vehicle for ", DaysRented,"days")
        print("\t\tThe vehicle's odometer reading at the start of the rental period is: ",Start_Odometer)
        print("\t\tThe vehicle's odometer reading at the end of the rental period is: ",End_Odometer)
        print("\t\tThe number of miles driven during the rental period is: ",End_Odometer - Start_Odometer)
        print("\t\tTotal summary for the rental period is: ", "($",DaysCost, " for ",DaysRented," days and $", DistanceCost, " for ", End_Odometer - Start_Odometer, " miles = $",Bill,")")
    elif ClassCode.upper() == "D" and End_Odometer - Start_Odometer >= 150 :
        DaysCost = (DaysRented * 60)
        DistanceCost = (((End_Odometer - Start_Odometer) - 150) * 0.3)        
        Bill = DaysCost + DistanceCost
        FullClassCode = "Daily"
        print()
        print('\033[4m{}\033[0m'.format('Welcome to JDB Car Rental Service'))
        print("Customer Bill (",(Name),")")
        print()
        print("\t\tClassification code is ",ClassCode,"(",FullClassCode,"):")
        print("\t\tRented the vehicle for ", DaysRented,"days")
        print("\t\tThe vehicle's odometer reading at the start of the rental period is: ",Start_Odometer)
        print("\t\tThe vehicle's odometer reading at the end of the rental period is: ",End_Odometer)
        print("\t\tThe number of miles driven during the rental period is: ",End_Odometer - Start_Odometer)
        print("\t\tTotal summary for the rental period is: ", "($",DaysCost, " for ",DaysRented," days and $", DistanceCost, " for ", End_Odometer - Start_Odometer, " miles = $",Bill,")")
    elif ClassCode.upper() == "Q" :
        break
    elif ClassCode.upper() != "B" :
        FullClassCode = "Error"
        DaysCost = (DaysRented * 0)
        DistanceCost = (((End_Odometer - Start_Odometer) - 150) * 0)        
        Bill = DaysCost + DistanceCost
        print()
        print()
        print("\033[1m" + "Please enter b for Budget, d for Daily or q to Quit")
        print()
        print()
    elif ClassCode.upper() != "D" :
        FullClassCode = "Error"
        DaysCost = (DaysRented * 0)
        DistanceCost = (((End_Odometer - Start_Odometer) - 150) * 0)        
        Bill = DaysCost + DistanceCost
        print()
        print()
        print("\033[1m" + "Please enter b for Budget, d for Daily or q to Quit")
        print()
        print()
    elif ClassCode.upper() != "Q" :
        FullClassCode = "Error"
        DaysCost = (DaysRented * 0)
        DistanceCost = (((End_Odometer - Start_Odometer) - 150) * 0)        
        Bill = DaysCost + DistanceCost
        print()
        print()
        print("\033[1m" + "Please enter b for Budget, d for Daily or q to Quit")
        print()
        print()
    else :
        break
```

**Author: Peter Jr**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## About `print()`

If you are trying to simply print a new line, you should use `'\n'` compared to empty `print()` statements.

```py
print("Hello, World! \n\n")
```

The code will print `Hello, World!` followed by **two newlines** as I have printed `'\n'` twice.

## Converting `input()` to different data types

By default, the data taken by `input()` is in the string form, or `str()`. This means that

```py
name = str(input()) # is the same as name = input()
```

But in some situations, you might want to take an integer value like the age of someone, here you need to convert the input.

```py
age = int(input()) # is not equal to age = input()
```

All good, but what if the user enters a *string* by mistake? We can catch this error using `try` and `except`. 
[Try and Except in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

```py
try:
    age = int(input())
except Exception:
    print("Error! Invalid input for age")
    age = None
```

This is a safe method, ensures that your program won't give unexpected results if the user's input is wrong

## Formatting strings

Use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) in Python 3 to format strings in the cleanest way.

```py
age = 14
name = "Monkey"

print(f"Hey {name}, you are {age} years old!")
```

This way you can add multiple variables, without making your code look *strange*

## Logic 1

you are doing

```py
classcode = input("prompt..")

if classcode.upper() == 'D':
   ...
if classcode.upper() == 'B':
   ...
```

Instead of calling `.upper()` for every statement, why not just do it once during `input()`?

```py
classcode = input("prompt...").upper()

if classcode == 'D':
   ...
if classcode == 'B':
   ...
```

## Logic 2

If you have `EndOdometer` and `StartOdometer`, instead of doing `EndOdometer - StartOdometer` every time you would need distance, make a new variable called distance
and assign it to  `EndOdometer - StartOdometer`.

## Use functions

The immediate requirement for this program is the use of [functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).

> A function is a block of code that only runs when it is called.
>
> You can pass data, known as parameters, into a function.
>
> A function can return data as a result.

You need to split different tasks into respective functions so that your code is more readable to other people. Currently, there is only 1 huge segment where all the tasks take place

- Move taking input into a separate function, wich will ask the user for the start and end odometer readings and other information

```py
def take_input():
    ... take input, the same as previous time
    return start_odometer, end_odometer, class_code, days_rented
```

This way in your main loop, it would look like

```py
start_odometer, end_odometer, class_code, days_rented = take_input()
```

The same applies to all other tasks, as the idea is only to split the work into separate functions.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your reply. I appreciate it a lot and I am grateful for the advice because I learned a lot.

Answer (score 5):

#### Variable Name

From [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
> underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the
> prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards
> compatibility.

Variable names in your code, for example `ClassCode` should changed to `class_code`

#### input() Function

The `input()` function return `string`, you don't need to user `str` to force convert it. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is the doc

But on the other hand, force convert to `int` is not safe, it might crash when user input something can't be converted to integer.

You can use `try/except` to prevent it, or use [str.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) to filter first

```py
days_rented = input("Enter the number of days the vehicle was rented: ")

# use try/except
try:
    days_rented = int(days_rented)
except:
    # Illegal input

# use str.isdigit()

if not days_rented.isdigit():
    # Illegal input
else:
    days_rented = int(days_rented)
```

#### The if/else statement logic

Codes in `elif ClassCode.upper() != "D" :` `elif ClassCode.upper() != "Q" :` and `else :` will never run as

```py
if ClassCode.upper() == "B" :
   ...
elif ClassCode.upper() != "B" :
   ...
```

already cover all conditions

And I guess this is also an illegal input statement, so you miss `continue` or `break`

```
if End_Odometer <= Start_Odometer:
        print()
        print("\033[1m" + "Please enter an ending odometer reading greater than the starting odometer reading")
```

In `elif ClassCode.upper() != "B"` part

```py
FullClassCode = "Error"
DaysCost = (DaysRented * 0)
DistanceCost = (((End_Odometer - Start_Odometer) - 150) * 0)        
Bill = DaysCost + DistanceCost
print()
print()
print("\033[1m" + "Please enter b for Budget, d for Daily or q to Quit")
print()
print()
```

These variables have not be used: `FullClassCode`, `DaysCost`, `DistanceCost`, `Bill`, maybe just remove them.

Comment: `except Exception` compared to `except`. try doing Cntl + C when using `excpetion`, it will catch that as an error

Comment: `isdigit` returns true for some cases generally not considered digits, and for which `int` raises an exception. One example is `str.isdigit("²") == True`. `str.isdecimal` does not have this problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your reply. I appreciate it a lot and I am grateful for the advice because I learned a lot.